# Python - audio signals similarity

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition

I'm working on a project in which I need to provide a functionality for 2 audio samples comparison, that returns a similarity value.

For example, I want to compare a kid saying "Hello" to Google Translate's bot saying "Hello" and get an indication for how similar they are.

I read about DTW and found it not useful (?), and couldn't find a library that does what I'm asking for.

Comment: Pronunciation scoring can be done withe specialized service, for example https://ispikit.com

Comment: Also http://www.soapboxlabs.com

Comment: Hello, StackOverflow is not correct site to ask for software/library recommendations. This question will likely be closed off. I would recommend asking same question in  official site for "software recommendation" at stackexchange. See link: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Anil_M thank you :) And sorry